# Solving integrals of functions of Jacobi elliptic amplitudes

Tags: calculus, integration, elliptic-integrals

I have an integral on the form $\int \operatorname{dn}(\frac{x}{k},k^2)^2 + \sin({N\pi/2} + \operatorname{am}(\frac{x}{k}, k^2))^2dx$, anyone know of any good sources or solution methods for suchs an integral?

Comment: Is $\sin({N\pi/2} + \operatorname{am}(\frac{x}{k}, k^2))^2$ supported to be meromorphic? What are the negative and constant Laurent coefficients at the poles? Elliptic functions are fully determined the two periods and those Laurent coefficients.

Comment: Not quite sure what that means to be honsest?